# finite field or order $q$

Tags: field-theory

Let $q=p^n$, $p$ is a prime number

Let $\Bbb F_q$ a finite field

Define function $f$ by
$$f:\begin{array}{l}
\Bbb F_q \to \Bbb F_q\\
x \mapsto x^m
\end{array}$$

$m$ is a natural number

Then what is $|\operatorname{Im} f|$?

It is easy when $m=1$ but I don't know how to generalize

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The multiplicative group $\mathbb F_q^\times=\mathbb F_q\setminus\{0\}$ is cyclic of order $q-1$.

Comment: I know that but i don't know next step.

Comment: I tried to find a kernel of f, but that is hard..

Comment: Oh I solve it! Thank you!